# Are there any conditions under which the Christoffel symbols can be treated as a damping term in a harmonic oscillator?

Tags: general-relativity, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, harmonic-oscillator

(Mathjax did not seem to be working as I composed this question.  Hopefully it will kick into action once I post.)

Note I am a novice at tensor notation.

I am working with the following Lagrangian (in matrix notation):

$$L=\mathbf{\dot{x}'Q\dot{x}}-\lambda \mathbf{x'x}$$

where $\mathbf{Q}$ is the metric tensor.

I think in tensor notation this would be:

$$L=g_{ij} \dot{x}^i \dot{x}^j-\lambda x^i x_i$$

In Cartesian coordinates, the Euler-Lagrange condition gives me (matrix notation):

$$\mathbf{Q \ddot{x}}=-\lambda \mathbf{x}$$

Question 1: How would I write this in tensor notation to isolate the acceleration term and get a harmonic oscillator.

In non-Cartesian coordinates, the E-L condition gives (in somewhat creative matrix notation):

$$\mathbf{Q \ddot{x}}=\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{\dot{x}'} \partial_k \mathbf{Q \dot{x}}-\frac{d \mathbf{Q}}{dt}\mathbf{\dot{x}}-\lambda \mathbf{x}$$

Where in tensor notation the terms

$$\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{\dot{x}'} \partial_k \mathbf{Q \dot{x}}-\frac{d \mathbf{Q}}{dt}\mathbf{\dot{x}}$$

Would be denoted using the Christoffel symbols of the first kind:

$$\Gamma_{ijk}\dot{x}^i \dot{x}^j$$

Question 2: How would I express this non-Cartesian case in tensor notation?

Question 3: Is it possible to get a harmonic oscillator *with a damping term* out of this case?  I think for this to happen it would have to be possible to show that:

$$\Gamma^k_{ij} \dot{x}^i \dot{x}^j= a \dot{x}^k$$

where $a$ is a constant.  This would then be the damping term.  Are there any realistic conditions under which this is true?

Comment: $x$ is a *coordinate*, not a tangent vector: $x^i x_j$ doesn't make sense, you can't lower the index of a coordinate, that should be $\sum_i (x^i)^2.$ Why are you attempting to write a problem in differential geometric language when the $\mathbf{x}'\mathbf{x}$ term there *explicitly* relies on $\mathbf{x}$ being a vector, and on the origin being fixed? Coordinates in differential geometry aren't vectors, so you should not use differential geometric language here.

Comment: @ACuriousMind The indices of coordinates (vector components) can be raised and lowered in the tensor analysis/GR texts I have consulted. For eg., "Tensor Analysis," by Lebedev ch. 2.  Anyways, the motivation for using tensor notation--the Christoffel symbols in particular--is to avoid having to get creative with matrix notation, as I was forced to do in the fourth displayed equation of my post.

Comment: On what page does Lebedev & Cloud claim you can lower the index of a coordinate?

Comment: @ocel07 You can find instances of $x_i$ and $x^i$ throughout chapter 2, and probably most of the book.  It starts where L & C introduce reciprocal bases, especially Eq. 2.3 and the subsequent displayed equations, on pg. 13 of my copy.  I readily admit that it's quite possible that I have failed to understand something elementary about all of this.